# Incorrect syntax error in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a nested if statement stored procedure, but it is giving me error:

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SPCRMDoctorRequestList, Line 28
>
>   Incorrect syntax near 'DR'.*

(*That is in second if statement's else part*)

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPCRMList]
@Records INT,
@Type VARCHAR(10),  /*Recent, Priority, Pending, Approved*/
@ViewType VARCHAR(10)   /*Dashboard, List*/
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF (@Type = 'Recent')
BEGIN
    IF(@ViewType = 'Dashboard')
    BEGIN
        Select top (@Records)
        DR.Id AS Id,    /*Unique ID*/
        USERS.USERNAME AS Requester_Name,       /*Employee Name*/
        ST.ServiceName AS Service_Type_Name,    /*Nature of Service*/
        DR.Date_Created AS Date_Created    /*Created Date*/
        From [Doctor_Request] AS DR
        JOIN [ASES].[dbo].[USERS] AS USERS
        ON DR.Requester COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = USERS.RID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
        JOIN [SERVICE_TYPE] AS ST
        ON DR.Service_Type_Id=ST.Id
        WHERE DR.Is_Deleted=0
        ORDER BY DR.Date_Created DESC
    END
    ELSE IF (@ViewType = 'List')
    BEGIN
        Select top (@Records)
        DR.Id AS Id,    /*Unique ID*/
        USERS.USERNAME AS Requester_Name,       /*Employee Name*/
        ST.ServiceName AS Service_Type_Name,    /*Nature of Service*/
        DR.Date_Created AS Date_Created    /*Created Date*/
            DR.State AS State /*State of Request*/
            DR.Deadline AS Deadline /*Deadline of request*/
        From [Doctor_Request] AS DR
        JOIN [USERS] AS USERS
        ON DR.Requester COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = USERS.RID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
        JOIN [SERVICE_TYPE] AS ST
        ON DR.Service_Type_Id=ST.Id
        WHERE DR.Is_Deleted=0
        ORDER BY DR.Date_Created DESC
    END
END
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not defined table Alias `DR` in your *both queries*. For example it should be like

```
Select DR.colName, X.colName
from Table1 DR join Table2 X on DR.id = X.id
...
```

Also in your *second query* you need to add a `commas` next to columns after `Date_Created`... as

```
SELECT ...
    DR.Date_Created AS Date_Created,    /*Created Date*/
    DR.State AS State, /*State of Request*/
    DR.Deadline AS Deadline /*Deadline of request*/
FROM ...
```